# What is the purpose of characters ".*" in command "sudo dmicode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB"?

Tags: linux, memory

The answer to the physical RAM question is:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB" | awk '{s+=$2} END {print s / 1024 "GB"}'
```

Above code gives the correct answer of 8GB on this computer with Unbutu 20.04.3

Please explain why?

There are 4 records (4 rows) with this `dmidecode` command that greps with "MB:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB"

Size: 2048 MB
Size: 2048 MB
Size: 2048 MB
Size: 2048 MB
```

There are 5 records (5 rows) this `dmidecode` command that greps with "Size":

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size" 
Size: 2048 MB
Size: 2048 MB
Size: 2048 MB
Size: 2048 MB
Size: 4096 kB
```

There are 0 records (zero) with:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size**MB"
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size*MB" 
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.?MB" 
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size. MB" 
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size??MB" 
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size???MB" 
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size????MB"
```

Can someone explain how we get 4 records with:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size.*MB"
```

The 4 records correctly shows the 4 memory sticks of 2048 MB per stick.

Then awk addition correctly gives:

8192 MB = 2048+2048+2048+2048

Then awk division by 1024 we have 8GB.

Can someone clarify what the characters `.*`are doing in above?

Comment: “There are 5 records (5 rows) this dmidecode command that greps with "Size"” The last record is in `kB`. So if you grep with "Size" you get 5 records. But a grep with "MB" shows you only 4 records excluding the `kB` stuff.

Comment: The first question is somewhat unclear. You have 8GB of RAM, you're querying it using the appropriate command and you're getting correct answer - what exactly would you expect to see? Please don't answer in a comment, update your question instead. You're not getting results with some of those apparently because the format of the query is incorrect.

Comment: Question stated there are many examples of Zero records.  One example already stated _ sudo dmidecode -t 17 | grep "Size*MB" _ The question is at post bottom _ Can someone clarify what the characters .*are doing in above?

Comment: The relevance of Zero records brings focus to the 2 characters. What are the 2 characters _   .*   _ doing in above?

Comment: Ah. Actually no, they bring focus to themselves. I misunderstood that you need an explanation for them. Your first question _"why is this command showing correct amount of RAM"_ doesn't bring focus to those characters either, but to question _"why is this command showing correct amount of RAM"_. The `awk`example doesn't bring focus to those characters either, but to the fact that there's a second way to show correct amount of RAM. Your specific question about `.*` is what brings focus to those characters.

Comment: Read [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) and you'll see that `grep` finds a [regex pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and not a wildcard. Read also `grep --help` and learn about [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Comment: @joseph I actually edited the question to have a comprehensible title. The [original question](https://superuser.com/revisions/1679192/1) had the title, “How much physical RAM is installed? Explain”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer's in `man grep`: [REGEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

As per grep [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

```
The period . matches any single character.
*  The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
```

Command  `grep "Size.*MB"` translates to:

*Print all lines containing exact pattern "Size" followed by exact pattern "MB", regardless of how many characters are between the patterns.*

The command would also display lines:

```
SizeMB
Size do-be do-be doo MB
easd EdsSizei up@#$Ahfu e8MBGj;eh di uh7987 p*&(8
```